# Block or detect key events coming from inside autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with multiple stacked `<input type="text">` boxes, and I check for an "Enter" press on the form's `keydown` event, moving to the next input down if this happens, and returning false to prevent form submission.  (Yes, that's the oldschool way... but I want to support legacy browsers).

```
form.onkeydown = checkEnter;
```

and

```
function checkEnter(e)
{
  e = e||window.event;
  var el, tag, typ, k = e.keyCode||e.which;
  if ((k===13)&&(el = e.target||e.srcElement)&&(((tag = el.tagName)==="SELECT")||((tag==="INPUT")&&((typ = el.type)!=="submit")&&(typ!=="reset")&&(typ!=="button"))))
  {
    // focus next form element
    // ...
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

The problem is that if I press down-arrow in an input and the autocomplete list opens, I can select a value from that list using the mouse as normal, but if I choose a value using the arrow keys instead and then press "Enter" to select that value, my event prevents this from happening in Firefox 61 and Edge 42 (but it does work as expected in Chrome 67).  This makes autocomplete unusable without a mouse.

**My question is:**  Can I block keydown events from triggering when the focus is inside the autocomplete history list, rather than inside the element itself?  Or alternatively, can my event somehow detect that the autocomplete list is showing?  I'd like "Enter" pressed while in the autocomplete list to perform its default behaviour, i.e. selecting the autocomplete entry.

Note that Chrome is possibly avoiding the issue because the value in the `<input>` changes as you navigate the autocomplete list.

Note that changing to using the `keypress` event (instead of `keydown`) makes no difference (at least in FF 61).

Comment: I think a good way to go about it is to prevent the prevent the `<form>`'s `submit` event instead of the `keydown` event.

Comment: You should provide the name of autocomplete plugin if you use any..

Comment: No plugins!  I'm talking about *the browser's* autocomplete functionality.  Plugins are by nature much more amenable to tweaking from javascript code.  (At least, if you mean javascript plugins loaded by the page).

Comment: Let me rephrase, why aren't you preventing the default action of the form submit instead of working with key events?

Comment: @zero298 Just tried it, and it doesn't solve the problem.  Turns out that setting focus to another element in the `keydown` or `keypress` events is enough to cause the problem; it doesn't matter if I return false or not... so the whole block-form-submission aspect is a red herring.  But that gave me a hint, and I found an answer... posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that what was interfering with autocomplete was ***not*** the

```
return false;
```

Rather, it was the part where I set focus to the next form element.  This solved the specific problem I was having (note the change to `keydown` instead of `keypress`, it's necessary):

```
form.onkeypress = checkEnter;
```

and

```
function checkEnter(e)
{
  e = e||window.event;
  var el, tag, typ, nextEl, k = e.keyCode||e.which;
  if ((k===13)&&(el = e.target||e.srcElement)&&(((tag = el.tagName)==="SELECT")||((tag==="INPUT")&&((typ = el.type)!=="submit")&&(typ!=="reset")&&(typ!=="button"))))
  {
    // nextEl = form element to switch focus to next
    // ...
    if (nextEl) setTimeout(function(){nextEl.focus()},0);
    return false;
  }
}
```

i.e. defer the focus change until after the `keypress` event has completed, using `setTimeout()`.

So I answered my *specific* problem, of fixing autocomplete behavior in this case.  But I still don't know the answer to the general question as I posed it, i.e.:

> Can I block keydown events from triggering when the focus is inside
>   the autocomplete history list, rather than inside the element itself?
>   Or alternatively, can my event somehow detect that the autocomplete
>   list is showing?

For example, I have another page where I want an "Enter"-press in an `<input>` to perform a specific action, only *not* if it was pressed to select an autocomplete entry.

...So if anyone has a solution to the more general problem, please post it!